# UNIX semaphores

Tags: c, linux

I wrote an example program about UNIX semaphores, where a process and its child lock/unlock the same semaphore. I would appreciate your feedback about what I could improve in my C style. Generally I feel that the program flow is hard to read because of all those error checks, but I didn't find a better way to write it. It's also breaking the rule of "one vertical screen maximum per function" but I don't see a logical way to split it into functions.

```
#include <semaphore.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <sys/mman.h>

int main(void)
{ 
  /* place semaphore in shared memory */
  sem_t *sema = mmap(NULL, sizeof(sema), 
          PROT_READ |PROT_WRITE,MAP_SHARED|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0);
  if (!sema) {
    perror("Out of memory");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
  }

  /* create, initialize semaphore */
  if (sem_init(sema, 1, 0) < 0) {
    perror("semaphore initilization");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
  }

  int i, nloop=10;
  int ret = fork();
  if (ret < 0) {
    perror("fork failed");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
  }

  if (ret == 0) { 
    /* child process*/
    for (i = 0; i < nloop; i++) {
      printf("child unlocks semaphore: %d\n", i);
      sem_post(sema);
      sleep(1);
    }
    if (munmap(sema, sizeof(sema)) < 0) {
      perror("munmap failed");
      exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
  }

  if (ret > 0) {
    /* back to parent process */
    for (i = 0; i < nloop; i++) {
      printf("parent starts waiting: %d\n", i);
      sem_wait(sema);
      printf("parent finished waiting: %d\n", i);
    }
    if (sem_destroy(sema) < 0) {
      perror("sem_destroy failed");
      exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    if (munmap(sema, sizeof(sema)) < 0) {
      perror("munmap failed");
      exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your code is good, especially the error checks.  Error checking always takes
up space and can be distracting, but good error checking is a mark of good
code (and of a good programmer).

As you say, `main` is a bit long, but it can be shortened quite nicely by
extracting the two for-loops into functions.  You can also remove the duplicate
`munmap` call.  Here's what you get after the semaphore initialisation:

```
int pid = fork();
if (pid < 0) {
    perror("fork");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}
else if (pid == 0) {
    child(sema, nloops);
}
else {
    parent(sema, nloops);
    int stat;
    wait(&stat);
    if (sem_destroy(sema) < 0) {
        perror("sem_destroy");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
}
if (munmap(sema, sizeof *sema) < 0) {
    perror("munmap");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}
exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
```

Note that I renamed `ret` as `pid`, as it holds a process ID.   And I added a
`wait` call after the parent loop completes so that the parent waits for the
child to exit (`stat` holds the child exit status).  I also removed the word
"failed" from the `perror` calls, as the message `perror` prints will make
it clear that the call failed.

Some other points: my Mac's `mmap` takes `MAP_ANON` not `MAP_ANONYMOUS` -
which system are you using?  And also there is a `MAP_HASSEMAPHORE` flag that
would be appropriate here, although your system may not have it (no idea
exactly what it does though).

Finally, the `mmap`/`munmap` calls use `sizeof(sema)` which is the size of the
pointer.  If it works, I would guess that `mmap` is actually mapping a whole
page and ignoring the size.  However, it should be `sizeof *sema` or `sizeof(sema_t)`

Comment: Thank you for the feedback! `MAP_ANONYMOUS` seems to be better, according to `mmap` man page: "`MAP_ANON`
    Synonym for `MAP_ANONYMOUS`. Deprecated." I'm running the program on Linux (Ubuntu).

Answer (score 3):

- `main()` must always return an `int`. `return 0` at the end of your function.
- The [consensus](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/461449/return-statement-vs-exit-in-main) is that, when possible, `return` instead of `exit`.
- You could make a helper function that accepts a `bool` (from `stdbool.h`) and a `const char *`, and if the bool is false then `perror` and `exit(EXIT_FAILURE)` are called.

Comment: No. It is right, that the main function always returns an int. But you have not explicitly write a return statement for that. According to the C99 standard, the compiler does that for you: »5.1.2.2.3 Program termination [...]
reaching the } that terminates the
main function returns a value of 0.«

Comment: Frankly, I don't care what the standard says. It may be doing the right thing, but this is a matter of style - if there's a return value specified, supply it, for the purposes of clarity.

Comment: Thank you for your feedback! I also read the thread you linked to but I wasn't sure because most of the answers applied to C++ destructors, I'll use return then.

Answer (score 3):

One thing to note:

```
sem_t *sema = mmap(NULL, sizeof(sema), 
         PROT_READ |PROT_WRITE,MAP_SHARED|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0);
if (!sema) {
```

Failure in `mmap` will return `MAP_FAILED`, not `NULL` (usually I think `MAP_FAILED` expands to `-1` cast to a pointer, meaning your failure check won't work).

As for style: This is just an opinion, but I think your style could benefit from the concept of a "cleanup block".

For example, instead of this kind of style [paraphrasing your code, not doing literal quotes]:

```
sema = mmap(/* ... */);

if (sema == MAP_FAILED)
{
   exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}

foo = malloc(sizeof(*foo));
if (!foo)
{
   exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}
```

You could do something like:

```
   int status = EXIT_FAILURE;
   sem_t *sema = NULL;
   struct foo *foo = NULL;

   sema = mmap(/* ... */);

   if (sema == MAP_FAILED)
   {
      goto cleanup;
   }

   foo = malloc(sizeof(*foo));
   if (!foo)
   {
      goto cleanup;
   }

   // TODO: do stuff with sema and foo

   // mark success
   status = EXIT_SUCCESS;

cleanup:
   if (sema && sema != MAP_FAILED)
      munmap(sema, /* ... */);
   if (foo)
      free(foo);

   return status;
```

The benefit to this kind of style is that you can add any type of allocation you want (in between the other stuff, before it, after it, whatever), and you just need to add a quick line or two in the cleanup block, and suddenly, all success and failure paths get the resources freed.  If any of the intermediate steps fail and you wind up in the cleanup block, you can be assured that you're not leaking anything, and it won't feel repetitive to make that happen.

There are other variants of this, for example if you or someone you're working with has some religious objection to `goto` (even though it's the cleanest way to do error handling in plain C), on the slightly more repetitive side you could repeatedly check `status` to see that you're still succeeding:

```
int status = EXIT_SUCCESS;
sem_t *sema = NULL;
struct foo *foo = NULL;

if (status == EXIT_SUCCESS)
{
   sema = mmap(/* ... */);

   if (sema == MAP_FAILED)
   {
      status = EXIT_FAILURE;
   }
}

if (status == EXIT_SUCCESS)
{
   foo = malloc(sizeof(*foo));
   if (!foo)
   {
      status = EXIT_FAILURE;
   }
}

if (status == EXIT_SUCCESS)
{
   // TODO: do stuff with sema and foo
}

if (sema && sema != MAP_FAILED)
   munmap(sema, /* ... */);
if (foo)
   free(foo);

return status;
```

Comment: Add the individual `perror` calls back (which are necessary) and these approaches still have 2 lines per error...

Comment: @WilliamMorris - Yes, but as the number of things going on in the function grow, it will just have 2 lines per error (not, say, 1 to 6 if there are 6 allocations, as a random example).